# MySQL equivalent in MSSQL to assigning a variable and using it

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I tried finding the answer, but maybe I am too new to MSSQL, I come from MySQL, so this is my question super simplified to go straight to the point:
Imagine we have a table "Things"

```
Thingie | Value
--------+-------
Thing1  |   10
Thing1  |   15
Thing1  |   16
```

In MySQL I could do something like this in a query:

```
SET @halfvalue := 0;
SELECT Thingie, Value,
       (@halfvalue := Value / 2) AS HalfValue,
       (@halfvalue / 2) AS HalfOfHalf
FROM Things
```

Which would return

```
Thingie | Value | HalfValue | HalfofHalf
--------+-------+-----------+------------
Thing1  |   10  |   5.00    |    2.50
Thing1  |   15  |   7.50    |    3.75
Thing1  |   16  |   8.00    |    4.00
```

Looks pretty simple, the actual one is a tad more complicated.
My problem is, in MSSQL I can't **assign**, and **use** a variable on the same SELECT. And I can't find anything similar to this functionality on this simple level.

Any solutions?

Edit, this is the select that contains all those nasty operations:

```
SELECT
  fvh.DocEntry,
  MAX( fvs.SeriesName ) AS "Serie",
  MAX( fvh.DocNum - 1000000 ) AS "Número",
  MAX( fvh.DocDate ) AS "Fecha",
  MAX( fvh.U_FacNit ) AS "NIT",
  MAX( fvh.U_FacNom ) AS "Nombre",
  MAX( IIF( ISNULL( fvh.Address, '' ) = '', fvh.Address2, fvh.Address ) ) AS "Dirección",
  SUM( fvd.GTotal - ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) AS "Total",
  IIF( MAX( fvh.CANCELED ) = 'Y' OR ( SUM( fvd.GTotal - ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) = 0 ), 
      'Anulada', 
      IIF( SUM( fvd.GTotal ) > SUM( ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) AND ( SUM( ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) > 0 ),
          'Devuelta',
          'Emitida' )
      ) AS "Estado",
  ROUND( ( ( SUM( fvd.GTotal - ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) / 1.12 ) * 0.12 ), 4 ) AS "IVA",
  ROUND( SUM( IIF( fvd.U_TipoA = 'BB', 
                   ( fvd.GTotal - ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) - ( ( ( fvd.GTotal - ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) / 1.12 ) * 0.12 ), 
                   0 ) ), 4) AS "Bien",
  ROUND( SUM( IIF( fvd.U_TipoA = 'S',
                   ( fvd.GTotal - ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) - ( ( ( fvd.GTotal - ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) / 1.12 ) * 0.12 ), 
                   0 ) ), 4) AS "Servicio",
  ROUND( SUM( IIF( fvd.U_TipoA = 'N',  
                   ( fvd.GTotal - ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) - ( ( ( fvd.GTotal - ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 ) ) / 1.12 ) * 0.12 ), 
                   0 ) ), 4) AS "No Aplica",
  COUNT(fvd.LineNum) AS "Lineas", SUM(fvd.GTotal) AS "FCTotal",
  SUM(ISNULL( ncd.GTotal, 0 )) AS "NCTotal"
/* Facturas */
FROM OINV AS fvh
LEFT JOIN NNM1 AS fvs ON fvs.Series = fvh.Series
LEFT JOIN INV1 as fvd ON fvd.DocEntry = fvh.DocEntry

/* Notas de Credito */
LEFT JOIN RIN1 AS ncd ON ncd.BaseEntry = fvh.DocEntry AND ncd.LineNum = fvd.LineNum

WHERE fvh.DocDate BETWEEN ? AND ? /*AND fvh.DocEntry = 1108*/

GROUP BY fvh.DocEntry
```

Thank you all for your time. I will dismantle my query and re-do it taking into consideration all of your input. Gracias, totales.

Comment: Maybe try to describe what you actually want to do. Your current example could easily be rewritten to `... Value / 2 AS HalfValue, Value / 4 AS HalfOfHalf ...` but I guess that's no help to you, regarding the actual problem.

Comment: @JuanLescano . . . You are wrong about MySQL.  See my answer and the reference to the documentation.  That the code *sometimes* works does not mean that it is *correct* and *guaranteed* to work.

Comment: Yeah, will post the actual select so you can see its a bit more complex but I think the subquery is gonna be the way to go.

Comment: I surely made a lot of mistakes, will keep following this thread in case someone teaches me a thing or two :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *think* you can do this in MySQL:

```
SET @halfvalue := 0;
SELECT Thingie, Value,
       (@halfvalue := Value / 2) AS HalfValue,
       (@halfvalue / 2) AS HalfOfHalf
FROM Things;
```

But you are wrong.  Why?  MySQL -- as with every other database -- does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expression in a `SELECT`.  The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) even warns about this:

> In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:
>
> ```
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
> ```
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

In both databases, you can use a subquery.  In the most recent versions of MySQL (and just about any other database), you can also use a CTE:

```
SELECT Thingie, Value, HalfValue,
       (HalfValue / 2) AS HalfOfHalf
FROM (SELECT t.*, (Value / 2) AS HalfValue
      FROM Things t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Didn't know about that warning you just gave me, interesting information, will keep it in mind in future queries.
Did think of a subquery, didn't wanna use it, seems like the proper way of doing it, I still have learning to do.

edit: enter saves the comment...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: you can't do that in MSSQL, because when you try it you'll get:

> Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

which you most probably experienced.

The most simple workaround would be:

```
SELECT Thingie, Value, Value/2, Value/4 from Things
```

Other method:

```
select Thingie, Value, HalfValue, HalfValue / 2 from (
    SELECT Thingie, Value, Value / 2 HalfValue from Things
) a
```

Answer (score -2):

No, that doesn't work in SQL. The parameter value is not set until the query completes. You can do it in two steps:

```
DECLARE @halfvalue FLOAT = 0;

SELECT @halfvalue = ([Value] / 2)
FROM Things ;

SELECT Thingie
    , [Value]
    , HalfValue = [Value]/2
    , HalfAgainValue = @halfvalue / 2
FROM Things ;
```

Comment: to my humble knowledge, we cannot combine a variable with a data-retrieval operations in SQL Server. Variable must be assigned alone or with other variables (SET OR SELECT) then it can be used in data-retrieval operations.

Comment: My bad, removed retrieval from the first query.